# Restart service in android when service is stopped from settings for mqtt notifications

Tags: android, service, mqtt

I am using mqtt for android push notifications.
For this my `MQTTservice` has to be always running.
If the user stops the service from settings, i need to restart the service.

My service is kept `START_STICKY` but when stopping the service from settings, the service is not restarted.

Can i use  `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` for this purpose? If so, how to use it?

I have subscribed my client with mqtt broker. when service is stopped, i tried to start the service from onDestroy method which creates a new service. Hence my old subscription remains unsubscribed. And a new subscription is made. In that case, how can i unsubscribe the old client? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Assuming you are using the same client id each time you connect to the broker, then the old connection should be disconnected when the new one starts.

Comment: How can i set the same client id when service is restarted?

Comment: What is mqttclient.LOCAL_ID and mqttclient.TCP_ID ? Thanks

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am interested in solution.